# highcharts heatmap items opacity turns to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, heatmap

I m using `Heat Map` of `Highcharts` library in my app and i have begin to face a weird scenario. The map does not show some rows data, plz look at the following screen shot:

[image]

I see data in the column when I `Inspect Element` a cell. I noticed that all the row cell's opacity is set to 0. Changing it to 1 in chrome shows the item.

[image]

My JS code is as follows:

```
$highchart1.highcharts({
            exporting: false,
            credits: false,

            chart: {
                type: 'heatmap',
                marginTop: 40,
                marginBottom: 120
            },


            title: {
                align: 'left',
                text: 'Some chart title',
                style: { color: 'red' }
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: pillarOrClusters,
                labels: {
                    style: { color: '#000' }
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                categories: locations,
                title: summary.locationType,
                labels: {
                    style: { color: '#000' }
                }
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 0,
                minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> has <br><b>' +
                        this.point.value + '</b> items in <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Pillars per' + summary.locationType, // Loaded from Service
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: data,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000'
                }
            }]

        });
```

Why would the map set opacity to 0 for entire row elements?

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle.net to repro the issue

Comment: Set `allowOverlap` option to true. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap).

Comment: thanks @PawełFus, but the issue was because of insufficient chart height as it's height would increase based on the yAxis data. So I would dynamically calculate the chart height and then set it at run time. Plz see my workaround in the answer i posted below. Is not there something built in to determine the number of yAxis data values and then calculate the chart height automatically?

Comment: Highcharts won't increase height for the container, as you noticed you need to set that height in options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being raised only in `Chrome` and sometimes in `IE` because of insufficient height of the chart. I am calculating chart height as per items on `yAxis` as follows:

```
//locations is an array of strings to be shown on yAxis
var chartHieght = locations.length * 35;
if (chartHieght < 350) chartHieght = 350;
```

And then set it as follows:

```
        chart: {
                type: 'heatmap',
                marginTop: 40,
                height: chartHieght,
                marginBottom: 130,
                backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
                borderColor: '#E5E5E5',
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 4,
                events: {
                    load: function () { 
                        //THIS WAS A DIRTY WORKAROUND I WAS USING TO MAKE IT RENDER PROPERLY
                        /* $(".highcharts-data-labels g").attr("opacity", 1); */
                    }
                }
            }
```

Turning the height calculation  as `locations.length * 30` begins to render the same issue in Chrome. `locations.length * 25` will cause the issue in `IE` as well.

Hope it helps someone.